# Passing Query Parameter in a json url not working

Tags: json, powerbi, m

I've been trying to pass a parameter in a json url to have the FromDate back to 04 months, for example, but it keeps bringing the whole year.

```
initialDate="&Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(Date.AddMonths(DateTime.LocalNow(), -MonthParameter)))
```

It results in the correct date, but I guess there is something wrong with the format it's brought in: 29/07/2019, while the original, static date was yyyy-MM-dd.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting it to a text format.

You can specify the exact format as below

```
Date.ToText(#date(2010, 12, 31), "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

[Details Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-totext)